# Trying to iterate through divs and getting "'NoneType' is not iterable"

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find and print the links that occur only inside specific divs on a page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://targeturl.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for div in soup.find_all('div'):
    if 'target-class' in div.get('class'):
        # find the link in the div
        for link in div.find_all('a'):
            print(link.get('href'))
```

When I try to run the above, I get `TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`

Is this because some of the `target-class` divs do not contain a link? And thus the loop can't iterate over it?

Comment: This error mean that you are trying to loop over something that can't be looped through - in this case you are trying to loop through something that returns `None`. 

Based on that, either `for div in soup.find_all('div')` or `for link in div.find_all('a')` is returning `None` because there were no matches found

Comment: @reallymemorable Please try to make your questions more replicable. Using dummy names such as target-class and targeturl means we can only guess why you are getting a variable valued None as there are 3 possible failure points in your code.

Comment: `find_all` shouldn't return `None`, it should always return a list, even if it's an empty list. So that leaves the other `in`, which ought to be the one on the line number that you got an exception for: `div.get('class')`

Comment: `if 'target-class' in div.get('class'):` I'm going to guess that the error happens here.  There is at least one `<div>` element that has no `class` attribute, and therefore this statement becomes `if 'target-class' in None` which causes the error.